# Flutter: notifyListeners not working for any page other than the home page

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My `main.dart` calls `wrapper.dart` (below). Depending on the global variable `loggedIn`, it shows either the Forms page or the Login page.

On the Forms page, the user can choose another page to go to. If I go to the Issue Parts page and change `loggedIn` to false, the app doesn't go back to the Login page. However, if I change `loggedIn` to false on the Forms page, the app correctly goes back to the Login page. Why does it only work on the Forms screen and not another screen?

Note - I don't want to overload this question with too much code so I've added only the bare minimum. If you think something is missing, please ask about it and I can either answer it or add it to the question.

**wrapper.dart:**

```
class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  const Wrapper({super.key});
  @override
  State<Wrapper> createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); ///Run this first
    initialize();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose(); ///Run this last
  }

  void initialize() async {
    final globalsOneTimeRead = context.read<GlobalsProvider>();

    await globalsOneTimeRead.localDBInit();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
      if (value.loggedIn == true) {
        return const Forms();
      } else {
        return const Login();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Forms Page:**

```
//...

return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const IssueParts()),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(formsList[index]['Form'], style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 21),),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );

//...
```

**Issue Parts Page:**

```
//...

ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {

    await globals.logout(); //sets loggedIn = false and calls notifyListeners();

  },
  child: const Text('LOGOUT'),
),

//...
```

Comment: how did you initialize globals?

Comment: @EdwynZN my main.dart uses a ChangeNotifierProvider to create the globals and then has a child Builder that returns GetMaterialApp (I was testing with the Get package but ended up not using it, I just forgot to revert back to MaterialApp).

Comment: I meant literally the variable globals in your Issue Parts page, I suppose you call it from context but wanted to be sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible reason:

1. `IssueParts` is not decentent node of `GlobalsProvider`.
2. You forgot to call `Navigator.pop(context);` after `await globals.logout();`.

Comment: `IssueParts` is a descendant of `GlobalsProvider` (it uses a `Consumer` widget to access the globals). I wasn't doing `Naviagator.pop(context)`, but I was hoping to not have to do this. I was hoping that the variable changing would automatically route back to `wrapper.dart`

Comment: It should show `Login` in `Wrapper`, which was covered by `IssuePart`. Without calling `Navigator.pop(context)`, it's impossible route back to `Wrapper` automatically with your implementation.

Comment: Ok sounds good. Thanks for your help! Do you think you could upvote my question so that future readers can see this answer?